# OpenEJB + EclipseLink are not able to create tables on HSQL database

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, openejb

I have a vanilla maven WAR project, using the Java EE web profile, that executes its unit/integration tests using OpenEJB. During the OpenEJB start-up, instead of using the data source defined in jndi.properties, OpenEJB creates its own:

```
INFO - Auto-creating a Resource with id 'Default JDBC Database' of type 'DataSource for 'scmaccess-unit'.
INFO - Creating Resource(id=Default JDBC Database)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Unmanaged JDBC Database, type=Resource, provider-id=Default Unmanaged JDBC Database)
INFO - Auto-creating a Resource with id 'Default Unmanaged JDBC Database' of type 'DataSource for 'scmaccess-unit'.
INFO - Creating Resource(id=Default Unmanaged JDBC Database)
INFO - Adjusting PersistenceUnit scmaccess-unit <jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'Default JDBC Database' from 'jdbc/scmaccess'
INFO - Adjusting PersistenceUnit scmaccess-unit <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'Default Unmanaged JDBC Database' from 'null'
```

And then, further below, when it's time to create the table - as per the create-drop strategy defined on the app's persistence.xml file - I see several errors like this:

```
(...) Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: type not found or user lacks privilege: NUMBER
Error Code: -5509
```

The jndi.properties file:

```
##
# Context factory to use during tests
##
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory

##
# The DataSource to use for testing
##
scmDatabase=new://Resource?type=DataSource
scmDatabase.JdbcDriver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
scmDatabase.JdbcUrl=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:scmaccess

##
# Override persistence unit properties
##
scmaccess-unit.eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing=JDBC
scmaccess-unit.eclipselink.target-database=Auto
scmaccess-unit.eclipselink.ddl-generation=drop-and-create-tables
scmaccess-unit.eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode=database
```

And, the test case:

```
public class PersistenceTest extends TestCase {

    @EJB
    private GroupManager ejb;

    @Resource
    private UserTransaction transaction;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager emanager;

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().bind("inject", this);
    }

    public void test() throws Exception {
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            Group g = new Group("Saas Automation");
            emanager.persist(g);
        } finally {
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like eclipselink is trying to create a column with the type NUMBER and that type does not exist in HSQL. Did you specify that type in your mappings? If yes then fix that.

Otherwise it might help to add

```
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="createDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="dropDDL_ddlGeneration.jdbc"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
```

to your persistence.xml so you can see what create table statements are exactly generated. If eclipselink is using NUMBER on it's own for certain columns you can tell it to use something else by using the following annotations on the corresponding fields.

```
@Column(columnDefinition="NUMERIC")
```

Comment: That solves the problem concerning the type, but it doesn't explain why a data source is still created when one is already defined in jndi.properties (and I also tried doing so programmaticaly, via a Properties object).

Comment: I don't know why OpenEJB does that. Might be better to split that problem of to a seperate question.